# How to schedule toast notification in delphi in windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I am implementing toast notifications in Delphi. My next challenge is to schedule toast notification to a specific time. I found the IScheduledToastNotification interface.

Does anyone have code example in delphi how can i use this interface to make a scheduled toast notification? Examples in javascript didn't help.

Comment: AddToSchedule method of IToastNotifier said "This method cannot be used by desktop callers." That means i can;t do it in desktop? Can someone please confirm.

Comment: While you can use the majority of the UWP API surface from a desktop application, you can't access any of the GUI classes.

Comment: So basically , you can only show the notification on desktop application and thats it?

Comment: @MickCic probably. But at least desktop apps have access to the [Task Scheduler API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614.aspx), so schedule a task that then displays a toast.